# search when press enter not when typing with livesearch.js

Tags: javascript, php, html

I tried to search when press *enter*, here I use *livesearch.js* for searching but this js always search when typing. I want it search when press enter. So iI tried change but still not working.

**Framework js**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="framework/liveSearch/livesearch.js"></script>
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="livesearch" class="livesearch" style="margin-top:0;"/>
    <div class="searchresult" id="liveRequestResults"></div>
    <iframe id="mainResult" src='log-list.php'></iframe>
```

**Javascript**

```
 <script>   
     $('#livesearch').keydown(function(e) {
         if(e.keyCode == 13) // I tried this code, first enter worked, after that back to search when typing 
        {
            liveReqInit('livesearch','liveRequestResults','log-ls.php','','mainResult'); //this search work when typing
        }
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you want a normal search box. This is going go submit the value to your backend(which I assume is log-ls.php).

```html
<form action="log-ls.php">
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." name="search">
  <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: i want edit the livesearch.js to normal searchbox like searching when enter, not searching when typing.